# Never actually adding the action? Or do I have to call the action?

Tags: theme-development, themes, actions

I have the following class that is instantiated in the `function.php` file. In the constructor I am setting up a activation and a deactivation hook for the theme. How ever neither seem to be called when I actually switch between this theme and say twenty fourteen and then back. As the echo statements are not called:

```
namespace Core;

class Activation {

    protected $themeOptions = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if ($this->themeOptions === null) {
            $this->themeOptions = \Freya\Factory\Pattern::create('Freya\Templates\Options');
        }

        if(is_admin()) {
            echo 'Sample';
            // On Activation ...
            add_action('after_theme_switch', array($this, 'themeActivation'));

            // On Deactivation ...
            add_action('switch_theme', array($this, 'themeDeactivation'));
        }
    }

    public function themeActivation(){
        echo 'activated';
        $this->setUpPluginOptions();
        $this->installPlugins();
    }

    public function themeDeactivation(){
        echo 'deactivated';
        $this->themeOptions->deleteOptions(array (
            'theme_options',
            'plugin_management'
        ));
    }

    public function plugin_install_error_message() {
        $this->themeOptions->renderView('plugin_install_error_message');
    }

    protected function installPlugins() {
        if (!get_option('plugin_installed') && !get_option('plugin_install_error') && is_admin()) {
            $pluginManagement = new \Core\Plugins\InstallPlugins();
            $pluginManagement->installPlugins();

            if (get_option('plugin_install_error')) {
                add_action('admin_notices', array ($this, 'plugin_install_error_message'));
            }
        }
    }

    protected function setUpPluginOptions() {
        $this->themeOptions->createOptions(
            array (
                'plugin_management' => array (
                    'plugin_installed',
                    'plugin_install_error',
                    'plugin_install_success',
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The `echo Sample;` is called when the theme is activated. so I know its at least getting here. But the other `echo`s are not called.

Can some one tell me why the `add_action` is not doing what I want it to? do I have to call `do_action`? **is there something I am missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `after_theme_switch` action but the correct name is `after_switch_theme`.

Also, you won't see the echo statements on `after_theme_switch` and `switch_theme`. To debug things in that hooks you can use, for example, [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php) function and look for messages in PHP error log file (you need to have errors "On" and/or WP_DEBUG enabled).

I've tested this and it works:

```
new Activation;

class Activation {

    public function __construct(){

            add_action('after_switch_theme', array($this, 'themeActivation'));
            add_action('switch_theme', array($this, 'themeDeactivation'));

    }

    public function themeActivation(){
        error_log( 'activated' );
    }

    public function themeDeactivation(){
        error_log( 'deactivated' );
    }

}
```